# choosing windowing function for audio signal processing

Tags: audio, fft

Currently I am working on chord recognition, and get confused on several aspect. One of them is choosing windowing for reduce the spectral leakage.

from what I read, hanning/hamming function is a good choice for windowing, but currently I read about welch windowing function, and its quite good either.

So, can somebody explain to me which windowing function I should choose and the reason?or are there any better windowing function?

thank you

Comment: For this type of application I don't think it will matter too much - I would just use a simple Hann or Hamming window.